# C# How to make one class instance available to another class method

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
Crew_Photos photos = new Crew_Photos(); // contains List<t> of photos
Bus_Crew buscrew = new Bus_Crew();      // Calls update.AddUpdate()
Cab_Crew cabcrew = new Cab_Crew();      // Also calls update.AddUpdate()
UpdateCrew update = new UpdateCrew();   // DEFINES method AddUpdate();
```

I'm trying to avoid doing this:

```
Crew_Photos photos = new Crew_Photos();

Bus_Crew buscrew = new BusDriver_Crew(photos);
    busscrew.AddUpdate(photos);
    
Cab_Crew cabcrew = new Cab_Crew(photos);
    cabcrew.AddUpdate(photos);

UpdateCrew update = new UpdateCrew(photos);
```

I do not want to pass `photos` to `Bus_Crew`, and `Cab_Crew`, only so that I can then pass it again to `UpdateCrew()` which is actually going to use it.

How can I make `Crew_Photos photos` available to `update.AddUpdate()` when it is called by `buscrew.AddUpdate()` and `cabcrew.AddUpdate()`?

Comment: your code doesn't demonstrate any issue. what problem when you implement 'I do not want to pass, ... '?

Comment: You don't need to do `BusDriver_Crew(photos)` and you can still have method`AddUpdate` which accepts Crew_Photos as parameter and you can  call method AddUpdate with `photos` passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a constructor for UpdateCrew that receives the three things?

```
UpdateCrew update = new UpdateCrew(new Crew_Photos(), new BusDriver_Crew(), new Cab_Crew());
```

Then the constructor can call AddUpdate() internally?

It's not clear what is happening within the different classes, so answering this question is very difficult.